# How to make navigation bar disappear when a link is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu navigation that covers the whole page. How can I make it disappear when a link is clicked on?

My code is below:

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
    <p>Menu</p>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu" id ="overlay-menu" >
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="#home" >HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".overlay" >ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="services">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" >PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ENQUIRY FORM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**What it looks like when a menu icon is clicked**
https://gyazo.com/24c86c1b1be45e18435ab275f550377c

I have attempted to use the `data-toggle` attribute but it's giving an unusual result.

```
 <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" >ABOUT US</a></li>
```

**Result - the last three links are snugged up at the top**
https://gyazo.com/bed757689c2a8c41cb8c7be25cc4008c

Comment: Shouldn't the `data-target` be `#overlay`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery:

```
$("#overlay-menu ul li a").click(function() {
     $("#overlay-menu").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use jQuery

```
$('#overlay-menu ul li a').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.overlay').hide();
   $(this).closest('.overlay-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it did work by making the links disappear but the button is still pressed and it doesnt re-show the links when the button is clicked upon.

Comment: your question was to hide navigation when link clicked, this site is about probmlems, questions and answers, not solution to whole project. Answer was provided for question, not for all next questions.